# amplify and subscribing after an even is publishing

Tags: javascript, publish-subscribe, amplifyjs

I'm using amplify to connect different parts of my views. It is hard to predict which script is executed earlier, so in one place a call to `publish` happens earlier than the corresponding `subscribe`. Is it possible to still catch all the missed events?

Comment: yes! try delegating the events. jquery does that

Comment: can you provide an example?

Comment: What if you pass data into publish function ?
is subscribe sees this data ?

Comment: No data, I just need simple pub/sub